# How to use Foreach data Codeigniter with return

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table `Claim`,

[image: Click to see table]

I need to get the data only for a specific name. For example: I only want to get the data from `id_claim = '2'`, before that I'm using this syntax in my Model:

```
function Tampil_claim_admin(){
return $this->db->get('claim');
}
```

But I get all of the data, not filtered like I need.
And I'm trying to do this in the Model :

```
function Tampil_claim_admin(){
$this->db->select(" *"); 
$this->db->from(" claim,artist "); 
$this->db->where(" claim.artist_name = artist.username 
    AND artist.member_id = ".$this->session->userdata('ID'));
return $this->db->get('claim');
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error Number: 1066
>
> Not unique table/alias: 'claim'

Here is my Controller:

```
function index(){
  $data['claim'] = $this->m_admin_data->Tampil_claim_admin()->result();
  $this->load->view('admin/v_admin_claim',$data);
}
```

And here is my View file:

```html
<tbody>
  <?php  foreach($claim as $data){  ?>
  <tr>
    <td>MSC-CLAIM-
      <?php echo $data->id_claim; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $data->artist_name; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data->claim_date)); ?>
    </td>

    <td>
      <?php echo $data->claim_amount; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $data->status; ?>
    </td>

    <td>
      <?php echo anchor('Claim/edit_claim/'.$data->id_claim,'Edit'); ?> |
      <?php echo anchor('Claim/delete_claim/'.$data->id_claim,'Hapus'); ?>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: have you tried using `get_where()` method?

Comment: can you show how to use it ? cuz I think my problem is only with model

Comment: you get data from two table so you need to use join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below query:

```
function Tampil_claim_admin() {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("claim c");
    $this->db->join('artist a', 'c.artist_name = a.username');
    $this->db->where("a.member_id = " . $this->session->userdata('ID'));
    return $this->db->get();
}
```